# Euler Tour in Christofides Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path, traveling-salesman

The penultimate step of the Christofides algorithm in solving the TSP asks us to find an Eulerian tour of the subgraph formed by uniting the MST of the original graph and MPM of a subgraph. I understand the starting point for the Eulerian tour will make a difference to the Hamiltonian circuit found after deleting the duplicate vertices in the next step. I am wondering if there is a way of finding what the best Euler tour would be? Or would you have to test every single one? This would seem inefficient for cases with lots of cities to visit.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You might want to look at: given a Eulerian circuit through all the nodes (sometimes repeating some), is there an algorithm to find the best Hamiltonian circuit (visiting each node just once) that "follows" the same order as the Eulerian circuit ("shortcutting").  What kind of problem is that?  I don't know by the way.....

Comment: I couldn't find a specific algorithm for this but felt like I was missing a logic step in the Christofides algorithm as it's used to solve really large problems to a good degree of accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of finding the minimum-weight cycle from the Euler tour computed by Christofides algorithm is called *minimum-weight Christofides shortcutting problem* [1]. Papadimitriou and Vazirani [2] prove this problem is NP-hard even for planar Euclidean TSP.

- [1] Deineko, V., & Tiskin, A. (2010). [Fast minimum-weight double-tree shortcutting for Metric TSP: Is the best one good enough?](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.0318). Journal of Experimental Algorithmics (JEA), 14, 4-6.
- [2] Papadimitriou, C. H., & Vazirani, U. V. (1984). On two geometric problems related to the travelling salesman problem. Journal of Algorithms, 5(2), 231-246.

Comment: Thank you so much!